# Is there a way to filter this request with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I need to make a query of all products but only with the category status in true,

The model of my products is something like this:

```
const ProductSchema = Schema({
name : {type: String},
category: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'}
})
```

Normally I would just make a query and then a filter for the products with category.

`status === true`, but the thing is that I'm using pagination and due to the filter my page of 15 products ends up with fewer products than 15 obviously because of the filter, so I really don't know if I can make the filter with a population in the query, maybe something like this:

```
const query = await Product.find().populate('category', 'name status')
.select(['-cost']).where('category.status')
.equals(true).skip(0).limit(15)
```

But sadly it doesnt work, is there a way to do it or should I give up?

Comment: please add sample input and expected output and also the `Category` schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with an aggregation:

```
const query = await Product.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'Category',
          localField: 'category',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'status'
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          "status.status": true
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          "cost": 0, // disclude
        }
      },
      {
        $limit: 15
      },
      {
        $skip: 0
      }
  ])
// passed the tests in my database
```

Comment: it did work!! i had to make a small modification Category => categories because i needed to put it just as it is saved in the db, thank you!! btw, i dont know to much about mongodb but i realize that if you use aggregation you cant use the other methods, you need to do all inside of the aggregation, am i wrong? its just curiosity.

Comment: @luislaguna Yes you are right. An aggregation can consist of multiple stages. This way you can have full control over the data :)